# Search under currently directory and sub directories for a string

Tags: mac, filesystems, search

How can I search all files under a specific directory that contian a specific string sequence like "superuser"

i.e. search for all files in the current directory and sub-directories (recursively) if they contain the world "superuser"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep's `-R` option does this:

```
grep -R "superuser" .
```

EDIT: to search only .mp3 files and return their names (not the matched content, since they aren't text files anyway), use find to get a list of .mp3's and then use xargs to pass them to `grep -l`:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "superuser"
```

If your version of find supports `-exec ... +` (and at least recent OS X's do), you can have find run grep directly:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec grep -l "superuser" {} +
```

Comment: Useful additional options: `-F` to speed up fixed-string searches; `-l` just show filenames, not matching lines (useful for binary files); `-m 1` stop reading file after 1st match.

Comment: how about for a list of files with a .mp3 extension?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Agree about `-l` and `-m1`, but I disagree about `-F` being faster (despite that being what the F stands for).  Traditional grep actually ran fastest (on large/many files) in `-E` mode, since that compiled the pattern into a DFA -- long startup time for the compilation, but once that was done it was very fast.  `-F` mode *might* be fast if your version of grep uses the Boyer-Moore algorithm (instead of the old naive algo), but IME most modern greps are adaptive and will choose the fastest mode automatically, no matter what flag you use.

Comment: @Gordon: Quite right, my mistake.